# adapter's getView not called after notifyDatasetChanged

Tags: android, listview, animation

Short Version:
The number of datasets in my adapter grows (from initially 4) while loading data. `getView` is called normally for positions 0 through 3. After new data has arrived (`getCount` now returns 7), positions 4 trough 6 are queried. Instead I would like to update the first 4 items immediately.

**My question - how can I make the `ListView` query `getView` again for positions 0 through 3 when `notifyDataSetChanged` is fired?**

The cause of this behavior may be related to some animations I do with the items in the `ListView`. My approach is loosely based on [Chet Haase's example](http://graphics-geek.blogspot.ch/2013/06/devbytes-animating-listview-deletion.html) - a `DataSetObserver` also receives my adapter's `onDataSetChange` (in addition to the `ListView`) and launches the animation by adding an `onPreDrawListener` to the `ListView`'s `ViewTreeObserver`. The animation is done in `onPreDrawListener` (using `View.animate`) and takes between 300 and 600ms. 
If I outcomment the line initiating the animation, the behavior is just like I want. `getView` is called for positions 0, 1, 2, 3 and subsequently 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

[image: LogCat excerpt from illustrating my problem]

The following screenshot (left) shows what the list looks like in this undesired state. Compare this with the logcat screenshot - the text on the views matches what comes after "View Text = " in logcat. On the right is what it settles to eventually after the ListView eventually decides to re-query getView for the positions 1-4.

[image: screenshots]

Comment: getView is only called for the rows that are being displayed, so if those rows aren't being displayed they aren't being created.

Comment: Good point but I'm afraid that's not the cause here. The views concerned here at pos 1-4 are being displayed. I will post a screenshot to illustrate.

Comment: Did anyone come up with a solution?